# Swift 2.2 - Correct way to programmatically init a UIImageView

Tags: null, uiimageview, swift2, initialization

I just got overwhelmed by the failure of this very simple code (which I separated from project).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var garageDoor: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let image = UIImage(named: "garagedoorclosed") {
            print("image ready: \(image)")
            garageDoor = UIImageView(image: image)

            print("garageDoor: \(garageDoor)")

            garageDoor.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 560, 400) // fails here!
            view.addSubview(garageDoor)
        }
        else {
            print("image not ready!")
        }
    }

}
```

I just want to initialize a UIImageView with an image named `garagedoorclosed`.

I have no idea why I failed to initialize `garageDoor` with `garageDoor = UIImageView(image: image)`.

My screenshot below:

[image]

Any comments is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit my answer. The main issue is declaration of `garageDoor` because `weak` means that variable doesn't retain the object and it will be deallocated. You have remove `weak` and `garageDoor` will be strong.

```
var garageDoor: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    if let image = UIImage(named: "images2") {
        print("image ready: \(image)")

        garageDoor = UIImageView(image: image)

        print("garageDoor: \(garageDoor)")

        garageDoor.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 560, 400) 
        view.addSubview(garageDoor)
    }
    else {
        print("image not ready!")
    }
}
```

The rule of thumb to decide which of the two references should be weak:

> think of the objects in the retain cycle as being in a parent-child relationship. In this relationship, the parent should maintain a strong reference (i.e., ownership of) its child, but the child should not maintain maintain a strong reference
>   [original link](https://www.toptal.com/ios/interview-questions).

Comment: Yes, this does the trick! Reuse your method, but after initializing garageDoor, I assign it back to instance variable, then it passes the error! You have any explanation about this weird case? Is this a bug of UIImageView?

Comment: It is not an error UIImageView. This is related to the concept of  strong and weak. I will explain in my answer

Answer (score 1):

in viewDidLoad just replace the below code.

```
var garageDoor: UIImageView!

garageDoor = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 560, 400))
if let image = UIImage(named: "garagedoorclosed") {
    garageDoor.image = image
}

self.view.addSubview(garageDoor)
```